# Any ways to increase hashrate?

Tags: hashrate, hashrate-comparison

I wonder why no one ever asked this question before...

#### Are there ways to increase the hashrate?

I know that overclocking and a CLI based OS **could** increase the hashrate. But I'm sure there are more than two.. What tricks are you probably using and what could lead to a better hashrate?

Thanks for your answer in advance!

**Edit:** I'm interested in advice for Linux and Unix

**Background**: I have a Raspberry Pi for mining and I got the maximum out of it (in my eyes...). Now it's interesting for me to know some of your 'tips and tricks'...

Comment: What about lets say talking on the things to do: such as tweaking the miner such as xmrig, the config tweaks to select, it would be good if we could share the tweaks (command based) both for the CPU and GPU if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite honestly, mining on a Raspberry Pi is never going to give a good hashrate. The processor just doesn't have enough cache (you need 2MB cache per thread/core) for optimal hashing. You can't even add a graphics card (as there's no PCIe slot).